# OpenSSH chroot breaks ssh and ftp

Tags: ssh, ftp, chroot, openssh, sftp

I'm trying to set up a webserver with a restricted sftp connection. I've googled and followed several walkthoughs that all appear to be pretty much the same thing.  Here are my steps:

Fresh install of Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS, with OpenSSH and LAMP ticked during install.

At that point, I can ssh and sftp in using the default account, and any account I add.

Next I modify sshd_config with:

```
## Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

## pam info here

Match group sftponly
     ChrootDirectory /home/%u
     X11Forwarding no
     AllowTcpForwarding no
     ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Manage the users:

```
# chown root.root /home/user
# usermod -d / user
# adduser user sftponly
```

After which, I can no longer ssh or sftp into the server.  What am I missing here???